# How can I set the selection caret to a specific point of a contentEditable div with multiple other divs within it?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I hope you are all very well.

Today, I am trying to place the caret at a specific index (`this.selectionStart`) of a `contentEditable` element which has other `div`s and `span`s within it.

The code to get `this.selectionStart` is already taken care of, we are now trying to replace  the caret once the selection is gone (due to a re-render of my element)

I have scoured the internet for help but I have only found solutions which work for contentEditable elements which do not contain any other elements.

This is the closest I've come to a working solution I think.

```js
        // this.selectionStart is the index we want the caret to be at
        // this.element is the contenteditable element
        if (this.selectionStart) {
            // We need to set the selection to the correct position
            
            // get the selection
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            // create a range
            var range = document.createRange();

            // set the range to the correct position
            range.setStart(this.element.childNodes[0], this.selectionStart); // error here
            range.setEnd(this.element.childNodes[0], this.selectionStart);

            // apparently this is needed
            range.collapse(true);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
```

This gives us the fun error of `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 15.` (when `this.selectionStart` is 15)

Please, I beg you, help me if you possibly can.

Thank you so much, this is very, **very** important.

Comment: @Wings Hi there, I did, but not in a simple manner as you'd hope. I ended up opting for a different solution where I wrapped a selection span around the text nodes where the start and end of the selection were, and storing the indexes for both of those. Then I just made a selection and extended it to the end selection span. I don't think this functionality exists without doing something like that.